# Android Listview - Persistant highlighting of items - How?

Tags: android, listview

I'm at the "I give up" point, I'm sure you know it.
I study Software and for my current project I am supposed to continue development of a half-done app that someone worked on last year. In other words I might not have a 100% idea of how everything works.

One error I wanted to fix was the ListView highlighting. This is how I understand it myself:

The app has a list of persons in a ListView, located on the left part of the screen. When you click on a person, it will show some stuff in the right side of the screen. When clicking a person, that person is highlighted in the ListView. That's all good and working as intended. There are however 2 minor issues, and I can't seem to solve them.

1: When starting the app, the first person is selected by default. That's OK. But the person is not highlighted. I am guessing I could programatically solve this in "OnCreate", but neither setSelection, setPressed, setItemChecked, performItemClick or anything else seems to do the trick for me. It might simply be a lack of understanding.

2: In the application there is a second activity. If I choose a person -> Go to the other activity -> return to the first activity, the highlight is lost. I have tried saving the position of the current item (pulling it from onItemClick) and then programatically highlight it again when returnng to the first activity. However, I run into the same problem: Neither setSelection, setPressed etc etc will actually highlight the person for me.

So I started looking into the XML files, which I am having a hard time understanding. What I came up with was that this XML file decides how items are selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />
</selector>
```

Honestly, I have a hard time understanding when it decides to highlight and when not. I would love an explanation or reference to this, I can't seem to find anything describing how it works.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the two issues, so highlighting works correctly? If you need to see any more code, please let me know, I was not quite sure what to post. There might be something basic that I have misunderstood.

**Edit:** This is the related adapter.

```
public class ChildAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Child> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;

public ChildAdapter(Activity activity, List<Child> items) {

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.activity = activity;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.children_list_row, null);
    }

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView countTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.count);
    ImageView childImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.child_image);

    Child c = items.get(position);

    nameTextView.setText(c.getName());

    if (c.getSequenceCount() == 1) {
    countTextView.setText(c.getSequenceCount() + " sequence");
    } else {
        countTextView.setText(c.getSequenceCount() + " sequences");
    }

    if (c.getPicture() == null) {
        childImage.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder));
    } else {
        childImage.setImageDrawable(c.getPicture());
    }

    return v;
}
```

To explain the context, every person in the ListView is an actual child. The View contains a profile picture (or a placeholder), and two texts (name and number of 'sequences' that the kid has)

Comment: please post your adapter code..so i will help you better.

Comment: The adapter code has been posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//Declare globally

```
 private ArrayList<Person> list_person = new ArrayList<Person>();
            public Person selectedPerson;
```

//Inside activity create

```
 selectedPerson = list_person.get(0);
```

//In adapter class

//inside getview method

```
    Person person = list_person.get(position);

        if (person == selectedPerson) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6E7C7D"));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

//and onitemclick change the selectedPerson position

Comment: I tried my best, but get stuck with a crashing app. It will give me a NullPointerException at this line of your code convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6E7C7D"));

Comment: I tried adding an if sentence so that if convertView is null, it does not run your suggested if-sentence. When I run the application it is initially the same. However if I enter the second activity and return to the first, the person is now still highlighted (Yay!) - However, if you select another person in the listview now, it will highlight as intended, BUT the person that was active when we returned from the other activity is also stuck in highlight.

Comment: Okay, this is my guess: The NullPointerException is probably from the first time convertView is used? And if I am correct I guess there is no way to avoid doing the null if-else check.
On the other hand, having it run with that fix, I am guessing that your line:
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
is never run (at least it made no difference removing the else-sentence), and that is why I can get two highlights at the same time. I am however not sure how to appropriately fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to put your adapter class code also which will give a better understanding. Come to your selector part, each item in selector represent a state of layout associated with the selector, like your first item say the background of list item will be look like "drawable/list_item_selected" if user have't pressed a item which is not selected. The items should be arranged in a specific oder. for detail check out [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

Comment: I updated the original post with the entire Adapter.